# How to parse hundreds of websites with same JSON data type using Python?

Tags: python, html, json

I am new to Python and currently working on a project that requires me to extract data from hundreds of websites that contains JSON data. I manage to scrape data from one website but have no idea how to scrape all websites simultaneously. Below is my code.

```
import openpyxl
import requests
import pandas as pd
import simplejson as json


url="https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?ageMin=45&ageMax=60&arrestWarrantCountryId=US&resultPerPage=20&page=1"

response=requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

data=response.json()['_embedded']['notices']
list=[]

for item in data:
    result={"forename":None,"date_of_birth":None,"nationalities":None,"name":None}
    result["forename"] = item["forename"]
    result["date_of_birth"]=item["date_of_birth"]
    result["nationalities"] = item["nationalities"]
    result["name"] = item["name"]
    list.append(result)

#print(list)

df=pd.DataFrame(list)
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Example of other websites:
https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?arrestWarrantCountryId=BA&resultPerPage=20&page=5, https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?arrestWarrantCountryId=BA&resultPerPage=20&page=1,

Comment: You need a loop to iterate through your list of websites. Also could you clarify, simultaneously or sequentially?

Comment: I have read some materials on the loop method. However, most of the websites I use does not appear in a standardized format. There will be differences in country code and search criteria on the hyperlinks. Let's say I just want all the data to be written in excel after the code is run(if possible), it does no matter if the result returns simultaneously or sequentailly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. You'll have to either add the urls manually or specify some logic to get them, I also noticed the json response has the url for the next page so you could have a list of all the first pages and use those to crawl through the pages, unless you can just get all the results in one json response. I also don't have excel installed so I used csv instead but it should be the same:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?ageMin=45&ageMax=60&arrestWarrantCountryId=US&resultPerPage=20&page=1',
    'https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?arrestWarrantCountryId=BA&resultPerPage=20&page=5',
    'https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?arrestWarrantCountryId=BA&resultPerPage=20&page=1',
    # add more urls here, you could also use a file to store these
    # you could also write some logic to get the urls but you'd need to specify that logic
]

def get_data(url):
    data = requests.get(url).json()['_embedded']['notices']
    # filter the returned fields
    return [{k: v for k, v in row.items()
             if k in ['forename', 'date_of_birth', 'nationalities', 'name']}
            for row in data]

df = pd.DataFrame()
# the data from each url in a dataframe instead of in dictionary for speed
for url in urls:
    print(f'Processing {url}')
    df = df.append(get_data(url))

# output to csv or whatever (I don't have excel installed so I did csv)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
# df.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Output (data.csv):

```
,forename,date_of_birth,nationalities,name
0,CARLOS LEOPOLDO,1971/10/31,['US'],ALVAREZ
1,MOHAMED ABDIAZIZ,1974/01/01,"['SO', 'ET']",KEROW
2,SEUXIS PAUCIS,1966/07/30,['CO'],HERNANDEZ-SOLARTE
3,JOHN G.,1966/10/20,"['PH', 'US']",PANALIGAN
4,SOFYAN ISKANDAR,1968/04/04,['ID'],NUGROHO
5,SOLOMON ANTHONY,1965/02/05,['TZ'],BANDIHO
6,ROLAND,1969/07/21,"['US', 'DE']",AGUILAR
7,FERNANDO,1972/07/25,['MX'],RODRIGUEZ
8,RAUL,1966/12/08,['US'],ORTEGA
9,DANIEL,1962/08/30,['US'],LEIJA
10,FRANCISCO,1961/10/23,['EC'],MARTINEZ
11,HORACIO CARLOS,1963/09/10,"['US', 'MX']",TERAN
12,FREDIS RENTERIA,1965/07/07,['CO'],TRUJILLO
13,JUAN EXEQUIEL,1968/08/18,['AR'],HEINZ
14,JIMMY JULIUS,1971/05/03,"['IL', 'US']",KAROW
15,JOHN,1959/10/28,['LY'],LOWRY
16,FIDEL,1959/07/25,['CO'],CASTRO MURILLO
17,EUDES,1968/12/20,['CO'],OJEDA OVANDO
18,BEJARNI,1968/07/12,"['US', 'NI']",RIVAS
19,DAVID,1973/12/02,['GT'],ALDANA
20,SLOBODAN,1952/10/02,['BA'],RIS
21,ALEN,1978/05/27,['BA'],DEMIROVIC
22,DRAGAN,1987/02/09,['ME'],GAJIC
23,JOZO,1968/03/03,"['HR', 'BA']",BRICO
24,ZHIYIN,1962/07/01,['CN'],XU
25,NOVAK,1955/04/10,['BA'],DUKIC
26,NEBOJSA,1973/01/08,['BA'],MILANOVIC
27,MURADIF,1960/04/12,['BA'],HAMZABEGOVIC
28,BOSKO,1940/11/25,"['RS', 'BA']",LUKIC
29,RATKO,1967/05/16,['BA'],SAMAC
30,BOGDAN,1973/04/05,['BA'],BOZIC
31,ZELJKO,1965/10/21,"['BA', 'HR']",RODIN
32,SASA,1973/04/19,['RS'],DUNOVIC
33,OBRAD,1964/03/10,['BA'],OZEGOVIC
34,SENAD,1981/03/01,['BA'],KAJTEZOVIC
35,MLADEN,1973/04/29,"['HR', 'BA']",MARKOVIC
36,PERO,1972/01/29,"['BA', 'HR']",MAJIC
37,MARCO,1968/04/12,"['BA', 'HR']",VIDOVIC
38,MIRSAD,1964/07/27,['HR'],SMAJIC
39,NIJAZ,1961/11/20,,SMAJIC
40,GOJKO,1959/10/08,['BA'],BORJAN
41,DUSAN,1954/06/25,"['RS', 'BA']",SPASOJEVIC
42,MIRSAD,1991/04/20,['BA'],CERIMOVIC
43,GORAN,1962/01/24,['BA'],TESIC
44,IZET,1970/09/18,"['RS', 'BA']",REDZOVIC
45,DRAGAN,1973/09/30,['BA'],STOJIC
46,MILOJKO,1962/05/19,"['BA', 'RS']",KOVACEVIC
47,DRAGAN,1971/11/07,"['RS', 'BA']",MARJANOVIC
48,ALEKSANDAR,1979/09/22,"['AT', 'BA']",RUZIC
49,MIRKO,1992/04/29,['BA'],ATELJEVIC
50,SLAVOJKA,1967/01/13,['BA'],MARINKOVIC
51,SLADAN,1968/03/09,"['BA', 'RS']",TASIC
52,ESED,1963/01/12,['BA'],ABDAGIC
53,DRAGOMIR,1954/01/29,"['RS', 'BA']",KEZUNOVIC
54,NEDZAD,1961/01/01,['BA'],KAHRIMANOVIC
55,NEVEN,1980/10/08,"['BA', 'SI']",STANIC
56,VISNJA,1972/04/12,"['RS', 'BA']",ACIMOVIC
57,MLADEN,1974/08/05,"['HR', 'DE', 'BA']",DZIDIC
58,IVICA,1964/12/23,"['BA', 'HR']",KOLOBARA
59,ZORAN,1963/11/08,"['BA', 'RS']",ADAMOVIC
```